# Python beginner: How do I get the sum of all integers between 2 integers?

Tags: python-3.x

So, I am trying to define a function that sums all of integers between 2 integers.

My code looks like the following:

```
def sum_range(n1, n2):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n1, n2 + 1):
        total += i
    return total

result = sum_range(n1, n2)
print(result)
```

It works well mostly, but when the parameter n2 has smaller value than n1 does, the result becomes 0. Why is it happening?

So if n1 is 3 and n2 is 2, the result should be 5 but it returns 0.

Comment: That's how [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) works. If `n2` is bigger than `n1`, swap them.

Comment: Is this question still open? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If n1 is 3 and n2 is 2 it cannot be 5 because n2 is exclusive.

[range syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

```
range(start, stop[, step])
```

If start is smaller than stop then step is important for range to work correctly.

```
sum(range(3, 1, -1)) // return 5


sum(range(3, 2, -1)) // return 3 

sum (range(3, 1)) // return 0

sum(range(3, 2)) // return 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I deal with this? Using something else rather than range?